# Perl: when do you use system() and when do you install the package?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I work in a project that uses Perl scripts on machines that are maintained by system folks, and installing packages such as Perl modules is no easy task - you usually have to call the person with the permissions to do that, wait several days, learn the API of the package, and then remember to install it on every newly configured machine ever installed.

The alternative that is many times chosen is just calling `system()` (or backtick notation, ``` `` ```, inside Perl) and using the output of the shell command that does what you want. Of course it's not always possible, and when it use, there is usually a wrapping to do around the command call, but it's generally easier.

My question is when is the trade-off pulling towards either side, in your experience?

Edit: adding an example:
I want to print the total size of a directory in a human-readable format, or list all regular files bigger than a certain size, and `du` seems to make this easier than installing modules that do the same thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue seems to be the perceived difficulty and length of time to install Perl modules.  I would identify why they have problems installing the packages and try and help streamline their process.

A common solution is to modify your process.  Admins don't typically like to install straight from CPAN, but as a developer you can use a local CPAN repo.  You "freeze" the packages you use there, and then promote them for use in production.

That said the trade-off between using modules or shelling it out as follows:

*Data*

Modules typically return structured data, shelling out returns unstructured text that you have to parse.

*Performance/Resource Usage*

Shelling out creates a whole other process, modules usually provide functionality within the current operating process.

*Additional Dependencies*

Shelling out makes your program dependent on whatever you're shelling out to.  Keep in mind that some basic programs change in output and behavior from OS to OS, so you may also be coupling yourself to a particular OS or set of OSes.

Answer (score 7):

Oh, that's an easy one. One always prefers modules because the tighter integration makes it possible to pass around data that do not suit the traditional IPC.

---

What, did you expect help in rationalising your suffering under crappy sysadminship?

Comment: Also, you can install modules into non-default directories, so you shouldn't need to call anyone with special permissions.

Comment: While I always preferred using modules over "shelling" out, I had heard of a counter argument that goes something like this: since Perl does not guarantee the release of memory occupied by a variable even after it goes out of scope, it is sometimes better (say, in a long-running persistent web application process) to farm tasks out to external commands invoked in a separate process, thereby not increasing the memory footprint of the main process. It may be slightly less efficient due to the overhead of forking, but the memory of the child process will be reclaimed by the OS once it is done.

Answer (score 2):

Modules, always modules. And, when I say always, I mean "almost always."

Modules are easier to control and to debug. It's easier to require a module be installed than some unrelated utility. It's more portable to use a module than to rely on the chancy command line syntax of a particular command.

Comment: What would you consider an exception hidden in this "almost"?  That is my question.

Comment: The exception is when the module isn't as good as the utility or for some environmental, procedural or performance reasons the command line version is better. This is rare.

Answer (score 2):

You have a [bunch of modules](http://p3rl.org/modlib#THE-PERL-MODULE-LIBRARY) that go with the core distro. Just use them.

You can install modules right in your home directory and when the time comes negotiate with the sysadmins: http://perl.jonallen.info/writing/articles/install-perl-modules-without-root

Comment: Great, thanks for the link!  It's easier than I thought, then.

Comment: As a sysadmin I would never allow the use of perl modules installed in a home directory in a production setting. It's bad production system management.

Comment: Of course I wasn't going to use it in my home directory for production - it's just until the modules get installed by the sys admins.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, always modules, because `ls` ain't `dir`...