# Perl Module vs External Command

Tags: perl

I'm inheriting a file transfer environment with a collection of scripts written in Perl running on Linux.  In a nutshell, these scripts just transfer files between sites using SFTP and SMB/CIFS protocols.

I've noticed that the scripts use Net::SFTP::Foreign for the SFTP connection handling.

Are there any advantages to using Perl modules to accomplish connections and transfers as opposed to just calling an external commands like `lftp` or `smbclient`?

Comment: Related: [when do you use system() and when do you install the package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545074/perl-when-do-you-use-system-and-when-do-you-install-the-package)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You usually get better error detection and reporting using a module.  I can't think of any good reason to change already working code to use an external command instead.

Comment: Plus it is more likely to work on other systems if it uses a module.